# How do you write "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!" in a movie script professionally?

Tags: creative-writing, screenwriting

> Stephen: I am your daddy.
>
> Robert:
> NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

The question is how do you write no in a way that looks professional without removing the "audio" information of how the "no" should be uttered by an actor, how long and loud the actor should sound like when he utters the line. How is this normally done?

Comment: Hi manocao, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about our site. This is a nice first question, though you could also generalise it to other drawn out phrases that require audio clues if desired. Good luck and happy writing!

Answer (score 6):

That many 'O's and exclamation marks is probably excessive, because it will spill over the line break. Beyond that, you're good to go.

Remember that a script should tell actors what they need to say, rather than *how* they should say it. How long the "NOOOOOOOO" is, is a decision for the actor, director,  and editor, so I wouldn't worry too much about there only being 5 'O's over 12. 2-3 exclamation marks should be enough as well.

Another option is to use annotations in the shape of [parenthetical-script](https://writebetterscripts.com/parenthetical-script/):

```
      CHARACTER 
   (trailing off)
Noooo....!
```

Comment: What about annotations (e.g. (screamed and trailing off) NOOoo!

Comment: You can do something like this:  

"TRISH  

Noooo…!  

(trails off)",
 

all in new Courier of course, with the correct page and paragraph format. This resource seems relevant: https://writebetterscripts.com/parenthetical-script/
For the parenthetical, the format is 3.0'' to 3.5''

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image: Empire Strikes Back original shooting script]
(Note that the "I am your father" line is in insert B - it wasn't revealed until the day of shooting - but the response is included here).

In this case, all of the interpretation of the line is left up to the actor and director.